# Why does Scala script not find class despite use of -cp option?

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala (2.10.1) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLASSPATH=${WORKSPACE}/play-2.1.1/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.1/jars/play_2.10.jar

exec ${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -cp ${CLASSPATH} "$0" "$@" 2>&1
!#

import play.api.libs.json.JsArray
```

and:

```
$ jar tvf ${WORKSPACE}/play-2.1.1/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.1/jars/play_2.10.jar | grep JsArray
  1401 Sat Jun 29 18:33:36 EDT 2013 play/api/libs/json/JsArray$$anonfun$$bslash$bslash$1.class
  2234 Sat Jun 29 18:33:36 EDT 2013 play/api/libs/json/JsArray$.class
  1517 Sat Jun 29 18:33:38 EDT 2013 play/api/libs/json/Reads$JsArrayMonoid$.class
  8358 Sat Jun 29 18:33:36 EDT 2013 play/api/libs/json/JsArray.class
  1368 Sat Jun 29 18:33:36 EDT 2013 play/api/libs/json/JsArray$$anonfun$apply$1.class
  6035 Sat Jun 29 18:33:36 EDT 2013 play/api/libs/json/DefaultReads$JsArrayReads$.class
```

yet the script isn't finding the `play` package much less the class:

```
$ ./setter-for-catan.scala
./setter-for-catan.scala:12: error: not found: object play
import play.api.libs.json.JsArray
       ^

one error found
```

What's going on and what needs to be done to fix it?

Comment: I don't see any errors in what you've written, and it works perfectly fine for me.  However, if given an improper WORKSPACE path (or the path to the JAR just isn't correct), then it would report that it cannot find "object play".

Comment: @James, my script actually has a hard-coded path and doesn't use WORKSPACE. Also, I have some Scala files that compile fine against the Play jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler daemon may be in a funky state. Try `fsc -shutdown` to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but the following works around the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLASSPATH=${WORKSPACE}/play-2.1.1/repository/local/play/play_2.10/2.1.1/jars/play_2.10.jar
classpath="${CLASSPATH}"
unset CLASSPATH

exec ${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -cp "${classpath}" "$0" "$@" 2>&1
!#

import play.api.libs.json.JsArray
```